# Storing,retrieving and display Videos from backend to Reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, database, amazon-web-services, server, cloud

I'm making web site where there are two type of users, the normal users and the videomakers , the videomakers receive video requests from users..  The frontend is in Reactjs the backend is in Nodejs, the authentication is managed from firebase and the users data is stored in a PostgreSql db.

Anyone of you know how and where can I store the videos that the videocreators makes?

Because I think that a good idea is to store the videos in some server and in my postgreSql db save the video_url... but I really don't understand how do this because the videos will be created from a videomaker every time a user request new one,  anyone can explain me a solution??

Thanks!

Davide.

Comment: you probably want to store the videos in S3, and serve them with CloudFront. Assign a unique id to video on save, save that id in the database. is that id on your front end when displaying them

Comment: mmh okey and Do you suggest me to use Amazon AWS services, for my future deploy?